# Live Magento 2 Site redirecting to localhost

Tags: magento2, redirect

My Magento 2 live site redirects to localhost

Already done:

1. updated database URLs in `web/unsecure/base_url` & `web/secure/base_url`.
2. flushed cache.

Anymore suggestions?

Comment: As well please check the app/etc/env.php configuration also

Answer (score 4):

Magento takes all config data from cache folder. You have to clear the **`<magentodir>/var/cache`** including all its subfolders.

Apart from that remove **`page_cache`** folder also.

Also check whether you have changed store URLs at stores level or default level.

Answer (score 1):

check following setting of your webserver:

PHP 5.5.x and greater versions

MySQL 5.6.x and greater versions

following extensions install on your apache server

PHP Extension curl.
 dom.

mcrypt.

simplexml.

spl.

xsl.

intl.

mbstring.

ctype.

hash.

openssl.

zip.

xmlwriter.

gd.

iconv.

writtable permission :

```
 "{"path":"directorypath/app/etc"}"   writable directory permission.

"{"path":"directorypat/var"}" writable directory permission.

"{"path":"directorypath/pub/media"}" writable directory permission.

"{"path":"directorypath/pub/static"}" writable directory permission.
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late, however I've just had a similar issue that has been driving me insane after updating, I hope this can help someone.

Turns out both of these variables in `core_config_data` on my end were set to the `websites` scope:

- web/unsecure/base_url
- web/secure/base_url

I set those two to `default` scope ran the following command:

`php bin/magento cache:flush`

And I'm finally in again!

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding some input here because it's the first question I found on google regarding this issue. I also faced it as well today after upgrading to 2.2.1 and in addition to deleting all cache folders for some reason I had to also execute

```
php bin/magento setup:db-schema:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:db-data:upgrade
```

After that I was able to get back to my normal URL.